# LDAP - ldapsearch command implementation on .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, ldap-query

I have to implement a "ldapsearch" query in my C# program

The flowing command  example show how to perform search on LDAP by ldapsearch tool from command line.

```
ldapserch -h sunldapa1 -D cn=netsst, o=catlg -w sstlws -b ou=users,o=catlg CUSTOMERID=1587445
```

The LDAP server is "Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition"

I try following code sample, it doesn't return any result:

```
var rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://sunldapa1/OU=users,cn=netsst", "catlg", "sstlws", AuthenticationTypes.None);      
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry) {Filter = "CUSTOMERID=1587445"};
var result = searcher.FindOne();
```

Could any one point me in the right direction please? Code sample will be very helpful